# Link a media wiki file to a new tab?

Tags: mediawiki

How do you make a wikimedia link to an actual file (let's say a PDF) and have it open in a new window?

This page was kind of helpful: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Linking_to_files#Link_to_actual_file 
Which showed me how to do this: **[[Media:MyFile.pdf|My Link Text]]**

However it doesn't show how to have the file open in a new window/tab. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it with an extension.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LinkTarget

After installing that extension as per the instructions I configured my **LocalSettings.php** file by adding the following lines at the end:

```
#Add Link Target 
require_once "$IP/extensions/LinkTarget/LinkTarget.php";
$wgLinkTargetParentClasses = array( 'ext-link' );
```

Then in my code I wrapped the media link with a span tag like this:

```
<span class="ext-link"> [[Media:MyFile.pdf|My Link Text]] </span>
```

Now the file opens in a new tab.